# Where is java installed on my mac?

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I am having trouble finding where java is installed on my mac. I am trying to downgrade from java 1.8 to java 1.7.

When I run the command  `/usr/libexec/java_home` it returns `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home`
but the trouble is when I go to the Library folder there is no Java folder. I've tried navigating there in terminal and it says `-bash: cd: Java: No such file or directory`

How can I get the Java folder to show? I was thinking maybe it is hidden. Or what other commands can I use that will point me to where Java is installed?

Comment: Hidden folders should be also accessible unless they are not allowed to be read, which is impossible because the app has to be executed by your running user

Comment: Inside of /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home is the installed location of Java.  The binary for Java is in the bin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
which java
```

This should give you the path of the java binary. It might be a link to another file, which you'll be able to check with:

```
ls -l `which java`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case Java doesn't seem to have been removed completely.

Go to /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane and remove it from command line. You might need sudo access.

Also remove the JavaAppletPlugin from /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
Again sudo access is necessary